# Ray's Zombie Conga issue

Tags: sprite-kit

Hi guys I am using Ray Wenderlich code from his book I purchase for the zombie conga. Okay he had the zombie moving around and thats why it did make sense to have his [self startAnimation]; function to run in movePlayerForward method. but my problem is that my player doesn't move but shoots stay at a same location but I have the shooting animation but its not running right. so where should I put the [self startAnimatin] cal and [self stopAnimationCall] in my edited code I am so confused.

```
- (void) Player {
_Player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player1"];
_Player.xScale = 0.09;
_Player.yScale = 0.09;
_Player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/4, self.size.height/2);
_Player.zPosition = 1;
[self addChild:_Player];
// 1
NSMutableArray *PlayerCh = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
// 2
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    NSString *mytextureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"player%d", i];
    SKTexture *ItsTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:mytextureName];
    [PlayerCh  addObject:ItsTexture];
}
// 3
for (int i = 3; i > 1; i--) {
    NSString *mytextureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"player%d", i];
    SKTexture *ItsTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:mytextureName];
    [PlayerCh addObject:ItsTexture];
}
// 4
_PlayerAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:PlayerCh timePerFrame:0.1];

} 


- (void) startPlayerAnimation {
    if (![_Player actionForKey:@"animation"]) {
          [_Player runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:_PlayerAnimation]  
          withKey:@"animation"];
       }
  }
- (void) stopPlayerAnimation {
       [_Player removeActionForKey:@"animation"];
}



- (void) update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
if (_lastUpdateTime) {
    _dt = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
}
else {
    _dt = 0;
     }
_lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
CGPoint offset = CGPointSubtract(_lastTouchLocation, _Player.position);
float distance = CGPointLength(offset);
if (distance < PLAYER_MOVE_POINTS_PER_SEC * _dt) {
    _velocity = CGPointZero;

}
else
{
    [self rotateSprite:_Player toFace:_velocity   
    rotateRadiansPerSec:PLAYER_ROTATE_RADIANS_PER_SEC*_dt*2];
    [self stopPlayerAnimation];
    //
}
}
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
        [self movePlayerToward:touchLocation];
        [self startPlayerAnimation];
}
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
        [self movePlayerToward:touchLocation];
        SKSpriteNode *bullet = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"mybullet"];
        bullet.xScale = 0.08;
        bullet.yScale = 0.08;
        bullet.position = _Player.position;
        bullet.zPosition = 0;
        CGPoint offset = rwSub(touchLocation, bullet.position);
        if (offset.x <= 0) return;
        [self addChild:bullet];
        CGPoint direction = rwNormalize(offset);
        CGPoint shootAmount = rwMult(direction, 400);
        CGPoint realDest = rwAdd(shootAmount, bullet.position);
        float velocity = 480.0/1.0;
        float realMoveDuration = self.size.width / velocity;
        SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:realDest duration:realMoveDuration];
        SKAction * actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        [bullet runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove, actionMoveDone]]];
}
```

Comment: Are you having an issue with your player moving, the shooting animation or the bullet moving at the target?

Comment: Hi my friend. how are you? and yeah bud the shooting animation is the problem. it sounds like the loop doesn't work and by the way let me go in to this original post and post that animation code too. please see the above code. thanks.

Comment: By the way I really, really I mean really appreciate all your helps bud sangony

Comment: I am a bit confused on what you are trying to accomplish here. Are you looking to have the bullet move from the player's current location to the touch location and then disappear or just move towards the touch location and fly off the screen? Also, what animation are you looking for the bullet to have? Is it just a simple path towards target or is there something more fancy?

Comment: oh not bud. the bullet is alright. everything with it is going smooth. the animation is for the player. let say the guy is standing and holding a weapon right and when he shoots he points right? now the animation for that weapon pointing is not working right. I putted the [self startPlayerAnimation] in the touchesBegan and [self stopPlayerAnimation] in the touchesEnded but it barely updating the animation frames.

Comment: If you are looking to have the player animation for pointing his gun run as soon as he stops moving, how about just adding it after [_Player removeActionForKey:@"animation"]; ?

Comment: my friend I have figured it out using this tutorial from Ray Wenderlich's site. but I have another issue. :] and that is the bullet spawns from center of the character not from the mouth of the gun. You know what I mean? I got position problem from where the bullet spawns. any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Congrats on solving your issue. As for the bullet position, I would suggest you use your player's position with an offset for your bullet sprite position. For example, you could use something like bullet.position = CGPointMake (_Player.position.x+15, _Player.position.y+20); you will have to use trial and error to figure out exactly what x+15 and y+20 should actually be.